# Update user meta on custom wordpress form and redirect

Tags: forms

I have a fully functioning custom wordpress form that updates the user meta when they are logged in, however when I submit it just reloads the same page I am on, I am trying to get it to redirect to a thank you page. How would I go about this? Current working code I am using below. Thanks.

```
    <?php  
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
    if($_POST['gender'] != '') {
    $gender_update = $_POST['gender'];
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID,'gender', $gender_update);
    }
        ?>

<?php
function curURL() {
$pageURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
return $pageURL;
}
?>

<form name="userform" method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="<?php echo curURL(); ?>"  >
```

Comment: Where is this code? In a template file? A plugin? Is it hooked to something? Also, you might consider validating that `POST` data before using it.

Comment: this is in a template file - will I need to validate that POST data if it is a simple select list?  Serious noob over here!!!

Comment: Essentially it is a form that the logged in user fills in which updates their user profile, but rather than reload the current page, I would like it to redirect.

Comment: Post your entire template, and yes, you need to validate the data. The form that prints on the user's browser is entirely under the user's control. The data you put there is easily altered. The script needs to protect itself on the incoming side.

Comment: OK thanks - here is the whole template - http://pastebin.com/yg6BReme

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to some other page, you can use [`wp_safe_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) any time before you echo content to the browser, including HTTP headers, which, I think, answers your question. But I would just `echo` a message on the same page if it were me.

Not really on topic, but there are a number of things about that template that do not look right. I can't find `get_header` or `get_footer`, for example. And you are trusting all kinds of user supplied data. Plus, that page will trigger a string of `Notice`s if `$_POST` is not set. Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see what I mean.